# Python 3.5 unable to import CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to Python and I know this is very basic. I tried checking other posts on this, it did not help, hence I'm asking again. I have problem importing csv file. The csv file is in same directory as my python file. Also I tried giving the absolute path, it didn't work. It shows the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FL_insurance_sample.csv'

I'm attaching the sample code below.

```
import csv

with open('FL_insurance_sample.csv', 'rb')as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

Comment: As it says, the file doesn't exist, you're providing an incorrect path. Is the `.csv` file in the same directory where you're executing the `.py` file from?

Comment: you shouldnt need the full path, check to make sure the filename and file extension are correct

Comment: How/where are you running the python? Where is the file?

Comment: also since you are using python 3, don't use `'rb'` use `'r'`

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this for being unclear what he's asking?

Comment: You should also be opening the csv file with `open('file.csv', newline='')`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Why?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen From the [`csv` docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):  "If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the `csv` module does its own (universal) newline handling."

Comment: I tried all the suggestions. I have experience working with MATLAB. So I'm well aware of the relative path and absolute paths. I run my python scripts as .py file. I tried adding newline=" ". It did not work.

Comment: Also I tried reading other files in the same directory. Like .txt files. They all open.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to open is not in the same folder as the python file. 
You have this options.

1. Move the file `FL_insurance_sample.csv` into the folder where is the python source.
2. Move the python file into the *file* folder
3. Use the entire path string to file. E.g. `C:\\path\\to\\file`, make sure to double up the `\` in the path or it wont work.

Here is a simple snippet

```
with open('FL_insurance_sample.csv', mode='r') as input_file:
    for row in input_file:
        row = row.split(',')    
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!. The above snippet worked. I gave the entire path with double slashes previously, it did not work. But now it worked.